# Lua arrays question

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, lua, lua-table

I'm a PHP guy so I don't know how to solve this problem. I know how I'd do this in PHP but I have no clue what the constraints are for Lua regarding this problem.

```
T = {
  clocktable = {},
  beancabinet = {},
  --...etc
}

T.clocktable[674] = 1
T.clocktable[660] = 1
--...etc
```

**Q: How would I loop through "T" to quickly know that the clocktable key includes the extended keys "674" and "660", only knowing "clocktable"**?

Note: please be careful of overhead as the "T" table will be very loaded with data and this is in a performance environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what the question exactly is. If you know the key, ponzao's answer is right, otherwise use a for loop:

```
for key, value in pairs(T.clocktable) do
    -- do something with key and value
end
```

Comment: We wouldn't know the key (674, for example) of T.clocktable. Also, we will need to do actions on each key.

Comment: @Geekster: The `for k,v in pairs(T)` syntax that Robin provided is how you loop through a table, you don't need to know 674 in advance.

Comment: Don't you mean `T.clocktable[674]` (without the second dot?)

Comment: @egarcia: I did, an unfortunate typo. Luckily Stuart P. Bentley fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason not to just check if it is not `nil`?

```
T.clocktable[674] ~= nil
```

Comment: We don't know "clocktable[674]" we know "clocktable" at the time of inquiry. The idea is to compile a list of keys so we can use the keys to perform actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for i, v in pairs(T.clocktable) do
    print("Key:", i, "Value:", v)
end

> Key: 674 Value: 1
> Key: 660 Value: 1
```